# Инвертировать в числе А n битов влево от позиции p

Tags: c++

Прошу помощи с задачей в заголовке!

Comment: а в чём проблема то? Покажите что у вас не получилось.

Comment: @droppenheimer  Не понятно, что именно надо сделать. не могли бы привести пример?

Comment: С клавиатуры вводится число, я перевожу его в двоичную систему, далее сдвигаю на позицию p. Мне нужно инвертировать - делаю, но как сделать это с определёнными битами - не знаю.

Comment: @droppenheimer Еще раз: можете привести пример того, что вы хотите получить?!

Comment: Пример:
Число 27.
11011.
Хочу инвертировать с позиции 2(четвёртое число в данном случае).
То есть получится должно что-то вроде:
00101

Comment: *"С клавиатуры вводится число, я перевожу его в двоичную систему, далее сдвигаю на позицию p."* Что значит "я перевожу его в двоичную систему"? И с чего это вдруг вы сдвигаете само число на позицию p???

Answer (score 0):

Готовите маску - биты в позициях инвертирования - единичные, в остальных - нулевые. Выполняете побитовую операцию XOR (`^`).

Надеюсь, создать такую маску проблем не составит?

Comment: Так вот вся проблема в этой самой маске, как именно её применить - понятно, но вот как составить...

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned a = 12345;

unsigned p = 10; // позиция, нумерация с 0 от младших битов к старшим
unsigned n = 2;  // количество битов для инвертирования

// Составляем маску
unsigned mask = (1u << n) - 1; // 'n' единиц в младших разрядах
mask <<= p;                    // 'n' единиц влево от позиции 'p'

// Инвертируем биты
a ^= mask;
```